# Are there programmatic ways of generating flowcharts?

Tags: .net, flowchart

Preferably in .NET but I'm open to anything.
I'm thinking of something where you would declare nodes and paths to nodes and you would render it as a graphic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# flowchart control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822733/c-sharp-flowchart-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [FlowChart.NET](http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html) would be of interest to you.

Comment: And now I look like an idiot :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have used SyncFusion's diagram tool.  They have one for Winforms, WPF, Silverlight and ASP.

I am currently using Nevron's.  Theirs is for Winforms and ASP.

Depending on your needs, Codeplex has an open source one called NShape.

CodeProject also has an open source one.  I have not yet played with either of these.

Answer (score 1):

Most great tools for this task are commercial, some of which have already been mentioned. Another option is [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_dotnetplatform_about.html) which is available for Windows Forms, WPF, and Silverlight currently. The website has a number of nice online demos for Silverlight (and screencasts for WPF and Forms) and you can evaluate the software, too, of course.

I like the Silverlight BPMN demo a lot:
http://www.yworks.com/products/yfilessilverlight/Demo.yFiles.Graph.BusinessProcessDiagram.html